# Resources for finding a German pen friend :)

Tags: resource

I know that maybe it isn't the right place to look for a "Brieffreunde", but I've looked in another places and I didn't find what I was looking for. So please, if you can help me, help me!

Ich studiere Deutsch seit 4 Jahren. Ich wohne in Tirana, Albanien (ein schönes Land). Hier gibt es eine "Deutsche-Abteilung", wo die Schüler mit den besten Noten das Gymnasium "Sami Frashëri" wählen können und dort lernen. Meine Deutschlehrerin, meine Geographielehrerin und meine Mathelehrerin kommen aus Deutschland, das heißt, ich bin immer in Kontakt mit deutschen Leuten, aber sie sind meine Lehrerinnen, deshalb kann ich nicht mit ihnen über viele verschiedene Dinge sprechen. Deshalb suche ich Brieffreunde. Ich möchte viel mehr über Deutschland wissen (Kultur, Schulsystem, Leute, Unis usw. usw.) und auch mein Deutsch verbessern. Ich habe auch DSD1 bekommen und nach 2 Jahren möchte ich (und werde ich... ;) ) DSD2 bekommen. Wenn jemand von euch sich für andere Kulturen interessiert (Balkan Kultur), bitte schreib mir ein Antwort. Wir können über Facebook, Whatsapp, E-Mails usw. kommunizieren.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about German language within the scope defined in the [help center](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: well technically it is not and i admit it.But we are humans,and as humans we should help each-other.if you can help me,than help me,if you can't than don't.ICH MÖCHTE MEIN DEUTSCH VERBESSERN!!!

Comment: @user16901 If you rephrase the question along the lines of "Resources for finding German pen pals", I think it would be more likely to fit within the scope of this website. Then we would be glad to help you. :)

Comment: Not exactly penpals, but this subreddit is meant to practice German: https://www.reddit.com/r/germanpractice